# Linked folder on window 8

Tags: windows, command, directory

How do I create a linked folder on windows 8.

I need to access folder c:\DirA using the path c:\DirB

This can be achieved using ln command in Unix.

I was able to access it using c:\DirB.lnk by creating shortcut but that's not going to work for me.

Comment: This is probably better on SuperUser.StackExchange. I'm voting to having migrated.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/391267/redirect-folder-on-one-hdd-to-a-folder-on-another-hdd-windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is a Symbolic Link or a Junction.

See the documentation here...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx

And an similar SuperUser post here that gives examples...

https://superuser.com/q/559547/140159

You can use mklink from command line to create one.

Example:

```
mklink /D C:\DirA C:\DirB
```

or

```
mklink /J C:\DirA C:\DirB
```

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for.
If anyone is wondering for difference between /D and /J its answered here: 
http://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link